# join condition is giving error in linq

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

i used below linq but it is giving error on first "join" keyword

```
(from st in queryResult.ToList()
 join rf in rainfall.ToList() on Convert.ToInt32(st.StationID) equals Convert.ToInt32(rf.StationID)
 join wl in water on 
 new { StationID = Convert.ToInt32(st.StationID), DataRecieved = rf.DataRecieved } 
 equals
 new { StationID = Convert.ToInt32(wl.StationId), DataRecieved = wl.DataRecieved } into gj
 from subpet in gj.DefaultEmpty()
                                     select new
                                     {
                                     Stationname = st.Stationname,
                                     Stationid = st.stationid,
                                     State = st.state,
                                     Datarecieved = rf.datarecieved,
                                     dailyrainfall = rf.dailyrainfall,
                                     cumlativerainfall = rf.cumrainfall,
                                     waterlevel1 = subpet.waterlevel1

                                     })
```

It is giving error "Does not contain a definition of "DefaultEmpty" and no extension method "DefaultEmpty" accepting a first argument.

Comment: What are the types of `rf.DataRecieved` (which should be `DataReceived` everywhere, btw), `wl.StationId` and `wl.DataRecieved`?

Comment: DataRecieved is datetime and stationid is int

Comment: Well if `wl.StationId` is an `int`, you can't join it with an `int?`.

Comment: if I remove int? then also same result.

Comment: Seems, you want to join `nullable<int>` with `int`. This might be the reason of error.

Comment: I changed the query and now getting another error.i am just editing my query

Comment: I think the correct method name is `DefaultIfEmpty()` not `DefaultEmpty()`